# How to send object in NSNotification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I want to send object to selector in NSNotification.I mean, I have 3 buttons and on click of each button I am registering notification and when that event occurred I am calling one selector and in that selector I want to find out which button user has clicked because I have common action for all 3 buttons.

```
-(void)allThreeButtonAction:(sender)id
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performSomeOperationWhenEventOccur) name:@"EventCompletedNotification" object:nil];
}
```

//Some event occurred, so I am sending notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"EventCompletedNotification" object:nil];
```

//Notified method

```
-(void)performSomeOperationWhenEventOccur
{
    //Here I want to know which button is pressed.
}
```

I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` from [NSNotificationCenter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You simply send a UserInfo containing whatever you need to identify the button (easiest is the pointer to the button) that you retrieve in your selector.

Your selector signature should receive the notification:

```
- (void)performSomeOperationWhenEventOccur:(NSNotification*) notification:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    // Use [notification userInfo] to determine which button was pressed...
}
```

Don't forget to modify the selector name when your register it:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performSomeOperationWhenEventOccur:) name:@"EventCompletedNotification" object:nil];
```

Comment: But how I will send button in postNotificationName:object:userInfo?I know which button is pressed only when I register notification, in button action ie when I call [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performSomeOperationWhenEventOccur:) name:@"EventCompletedNotification" object:nil];.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an object when adding a notification observer, so you'll have to store the button that was pressed somewhere:

```
-(void)allThreeButtonAction:(id)sender
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performSomeOperationWhenEventOccur) name:@"EventCompletedNotification" object:nil];
   self.buttonPressed = sender;
}
```

Then you can just read it in your notification handler:

```
-(void)performSomeOperationWhenEventOccur
{
    if ( self.buttonPressed = self.button1 )
        ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Below Snippet will help you.

**Button1**

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performSomeOperationWhenEventOccur:) name:@"button1" object:button1];
```

**Button2**

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performSomeOperationWhenEventOccur:) name:@"button2" object:button2];
```

**Change method to following**

```
- (void) performSomeOperationWhenEventOccur:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"button1"])
    {
        NSButton *button1=[notification button1];
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification! from button1");
    }
     else
    {
        NSButton *button2=[notification button2]; 
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification! from button2");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want button instance not only information which button is clicked.

Comment: If you want to pass Button object then why are you passing object:nil.instead of nil pass button object there

Comment: @Downvoter Please keep habbit of pointing mistakes and suggesting right solution (If you are kind enough).